# Outlook 2016, Windows 10, Outlook email in Explorer

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, move

Trying to do this in Outlook Email session on Explorer: but also I have the Application Outlook on Desktop. Really unfamiliar with how to operate the App, so please be specific in steps if it can be done there easier than in Explorer. THANKS!

In Outlook 2016, w Windows 10 OS, how do I move all files in subfolders to a parent folder? Subfolders and parent folders were created by me--not the default folders of Inbox, Deleted, Sent, etc...

I known how to do it one file at a time, but there are too many. I'm trying to clean up and sort my Outlook emails to prep for a backup to .pst.

Choosing "select all" files in the subfolder does choose them all, but will not let me move them as an entire group. Once selected, I get the CIRCLE-W-LINE-THROUGH-IT "no" blocked function.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Outlook Import/Export feature might be useful to you.
You could first export your items in the subfolder to a .pst file  like below:

[image]

Then select your parent folder and import your items with the options like below:

[image]

After that, you will find your subfolder items in the parent folder.